# Query mbtile vector at a higher zoom level while visualising in lower zoom in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, zoom, mapbox-gl-js

I've created five `GeoJSONs` for `H3 resolution` cells from 3 to 7. Each `GeoJSON` was then converted into `mbtile` for different zoom level and joined together to form a single mbtile. Now, I can render different H3 levels at different zoom levels but when I try to query using a bounding box I can only query the layer at the current zoom level.

I want to get the values (property of the H3 cell) at higher zoom level (10) but keep the UI at the lower map zoom level (3 or 4). What are my options to achieve this, is there a way to get this from backend, my tiles are currently hosted on tileserver-gl?

Sample Layer:

```
 map.addLayer({
    'id': 'your-layer-03',
    'type': 'fill', // or 'line' or 'symbol', depending on your tileset
    'source': 'ec-tileset',
    'source-layer': 'h3_cells_res_3', // Replace with your source layer name
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': [
            'interpolate',
            ['linear'],
            ['get', 'DAI'],
            0, '#FFFFFF',
            0.5, '#FFCCA8',
            1, '#FD6B20'
        ],
        'fill-opacity': 0.5
    }
});
```

Query Code:

```
function getH3Values(inputPolygon) {
    let nonEmptyFeatures;
    let layerNames = ['your-layer-03', 'your-layer-04', 'your-layer-05', 'your-layer-06', 'your-layer-07', 'your-layer-08'];
// Loop through each layer and filter features based on the drawn polygon
for (let layerName of layerNames) {
    
    let features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: [layerName] });
    
    //var allFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures('ec-query', {sourceLayer: 'h3_cells_res_7'});
    
    let filteredFeatures = features.filter(function (feature) {
        if(feature.geometry.type === "Point") {
            return turf.booleanPointInPolygon(feature.geometry.coordinates, inputPolygon);
        } else if(feature.geometry.type === "Polygon" || feature.geometry.type === "MultiPolygon") {
            return turf.intersect(feature.geometry, inputPolygon);
        }
        return false;
    });

    // If filteredFeatures is not empty, assign it to nonEmptyFeatures and break the loop
    if (filteredFeatures.length > 0) {
        nonEmptyFeatures = filteredFeatures;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(nonEmptyFeatures);

// If no features are found in all layers, log a message and return
if (!nonEmptyFeatures) {
    console.log("No features found in all layers.");
    return;
}

var featureValues = [];

// Iterate over each feature
nonEmptyFeatures.forEach(function(feature) {

    featureValues.push(feature.properties.value);
});

}
```

I'm trying to get data from higher zoom levels (10) while having the map shown at lower zoom (maybe 3) for entire country like USA or a bbox that is bigger than the viewport when someone zooms-in.

Comment: if the mbtiles are drop features at lower zoom levels(zoomed out 1,2,3 etc..) than I believe only the features you are visually seeing will be queryable. 

A workaround can be to load the geojson onto the map but make it completely transparent and query the geojson that way or use a middleware/backend service

Answer (score 1):

You can use my tool tilequery to query vector tiles using a point or bounding box. For polygons beware of the geometry since it will be clipped to the vector tile but you can access the properties no problem. You can see it in action on this site on the esri map.

https://reyemtm.github.io/map-compare//?map=esri-v4

I can add more details when I have more time.

Comment: https://github.com/reyemtm/tilequery

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create second map that's copy of the original one, but not displayed. This one can then be used to set zoom independent of the displayed map and retrieve features from there.

Code below is proof of concept. It's probably not the most efficient, but it works. It's modified Mapbox example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/.

Click on the map produces list of the airports, but at the zoom 5, centered on the clicked point, while displayed map zoom is not changed. Bounding box of zoomed map is shown with red outline.

Here is full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Filter features within map view</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.14.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 25%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 75%;
    }
    #map2 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 25%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 75%;
    }
    .map-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      width: 25%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #efefef;
      max-height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .map-overlay .listing {
      overflow: auto;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    .map-overlay .listing > * {
      display: block;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .map-overlay .listing a:last-child {
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map1"></div> 
  <div id="map2" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="map-overlay">
      <div id="feature-listing" class="listing"></div>
  </div> 
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';
  
    const map1 = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map1',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
      center: [-98, 38.88],
      maxZoom: 15,
      minZoom: 1,
      zoom: 3
    });
  
    const map2 = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map2',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
      center: [-98, 38.88],
      maxZoom: 15,
      minZoom: 1,
      zoom: 3
    });
  
    const listingEl = document.getElementById('feature-listing');
  
    function renderListings(features) {
      const empty = document.createElement('p');
      listingEl.innerHTML = '';
      if (features.length) {
        for (const feature of features) {
          const item = document.createElement('div');
          const label = `${feature.properties.name} (${feature.properties.abbrev})`;
          item.innerHTML = label;
          listingEl.appendChild(item);
        }
      } else {
        empty.textContent = 'No results found';
        listingEl.appendChild(empty);
      }
    }
  
    function getUniqueFeatures(features, comparatorProperty) {
      const uniqueIds = new Set();
      const uniqueFeatures = [];
      for (const feature of features) {
        const id = feature.properties[comparatorProperty];
        if (!uniqueIds.has(id)) {
          uniqueIds.add(id);
          uniqueFeatures.push(feature);
        }
      }
      return uniqueFeatures;
    }
  
    function listFeatures(map) {
      const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['airport'] });
      if (features) {
        const uniqueFeatures = getUniqueFeatures(features, 'iata_code');
        renderListings(uniqueFeatures);
      }
    }
  
    var source = {
      'type': 'vector',
      'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.04w69w5j'
    };
    var layer = {
      'id': 'airport',
      'source': 'airports',
      'source-layer': 'ne_10m_airports',
      'type': 'circle',
      'paint': {
        'circle-color': '#4264fb',
        'circle-radius': 4,
        'circle-stroke-width': 2,
        'circle-stroke-color': '#ffffff'
      }
    }
  
    const geojson = {
      'type': 'FeatureCollection',
      'features': []
    };
     
    const bbox = {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': []
      }
    };
  
    map1.on('load', () => {
      map1.addSource('airports', source);
      map1.addLayer(layer);
      map1.on('click', (evt) => {
        console.log([evt.lngLat.lng, evt.lngLat.lat]);
        map2.once('idle', function() {
          listFeatures(map2);
          var bounds = map2.getBounds();
          var east = bounds.getEast();
          var west = bounds.getWest();
          var north = bounds.getNorth();
          var south = bounds.getSouth();
          var bboxCoords = [[west, north], [west, south], [east, south], [east, north], [west, north]];
          bbox.geometry.coordinates[0] = bboxCoords;
          map1.getSource('geojson').setData(bbox);
        });
        map2.jumpTo({
          center: [evt.lngLat.lng, evt.lngLat.lat],
          zoom: 5
        });
      });
      map1.addSource('geojson', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': geojson
      });
      map1.addLayer({
        id: 'bbox',
        type: 'line',
        source: 'geojson',
        layout: {
          'line-cap': 'round',
          'line-join': 'round'
        },
        paint: {
          'line-color': '#ff0000',
          'line-width': 2
        }
      });
    });
  
    map2.on('load', () => {
      map2.addSource('airports', source);
      map2.addLayer(layer);
    });  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of the result upon map click:

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea, but, if I want to query features for entire country like USA, and i zoom into the higher resolution on this hidden map-2, will the query still work because the zoomed in map-2 now doesn't have full view or rendered features of the country but is only limited to the zoomed view.

Comment: Nowhere in your question you mention that  in higher zoom level you want entire USA data. Please edit your question and add that info. I'll see how to take care of that.

Comment: On a second thought: if you need all the data at once, why not use the original GeoJSON?

Comment: I'm not sure how will I render 5GB Geojson on the screen, because h3 10 cells are in millions, isn't vector tiling meant for this purpose?

Comment: What I meant is to use original GeoJSON just to get desired properties, not for display on screen. It could even be modified for this purpose to be without geometries, just JSON with properties. I suppose there is some property that identifies individual cell.

Comment: I already have that implementation on elastic where I query bbox for JSON records, its not as fast and neither cheap.

Comment: Vector tiles are intended to get detailed vector data in chunks for small area, but you want to get info from vector tiles for entire USA at zoom 10, which means more than 13000 tiles. That makes no sense and that's not what vector tiles are meant for. It's also not clear why you would you want to have data for entire USA at once? For statistics? H3 grid is not the right tool for that.